# Kendo UI menu open() close() not working in hidden parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

I've made an example: http://dojo.telerik.com/IyAFA

I have a sample menu and I want to close it in some events.
To test the example first drag over "Hover me" button (menu should be closed). Then click "Show Menu" button to see how it looks like.

I guess the problems is open() and close() function are not working if the parent of the kendo menu is with style `display:none;`. Anyone knows a workaround or a solution for this problem?

Comment: You're saying that the menu opens messy after you hover *"Hover me"*? Because to me, it opens messy anytime. It works nice if I remove `'li'` from the open method, e.g. `.open()` only.

Comment: If you remove `class="hidden"` from `'div#wrapper'`  see how the menu is opened - looks OK. 

Then remove `'li'` from `.open()`  the menu is not opened. - You should pass a selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some workaround: 
Before call `.close()` on kendo menu, the following line should be added:

```
  $('.k-animation-container').css('display','none');
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/IyAFA/6